# Object to JsonObject using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to post following string as json to the server.

> {     "FirstName": "John",    "LastName": "Smith" }, {    "FirstName":
>   "John",   "LastName": "Smith" }

But if I use below code, I am getting array list of json objects.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>() {}.getType();
String json = gson.toJson(list, type);
```

**Output:**

> [{    "FirstName": "John",    "LastName": "Smith" }, {    "FirstName":
>   "John",   "LastName": "Smith" }]

So can anybody help me to achieve this ? Or server guy made a mistake ? I want to submit it as a post method of retrofit library.

Comment: Tell the backend Engineer, you are posting array of objects as json, so he/she will parse it accordingly

Comment: best way to pass arrayobject to server

Answer (score 2):

> I want to post following string as json to the server.

Suppose you use header: `"content-type", "application/json"`

The string you posted - is wrong JSON format:

```
{ "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }, { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }
```

Your output is a right JSON syntax a.e.:

```
[{ "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }, { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }]
```

So use it

> Or server guy made a mistake ?

Looks like. I believe he thought about `[{},{}]` structure

---

Anyways if you want to send `{ "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }, { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }` - you have nothing to do with `Gson`. You got list of objects, just remove `[`, `]` from beginning and end

```
private static String removeLastChar(String str) {
    return str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
}

public String removeFirstChar(String s){
   return s.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: I know this as we have string and we can perform string operation to remove { and }, is there any correct way using gson to achieve this ? Because this is not a correct way to do, otherwise I have to ask server guy that this is not a correct way to do.

Comment: This is not possible with GSON, as the format you are asking for is not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Simon, it is not a valid json as I check with [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/). So I talked with server guy and changed to valid json like

> [{ "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith" }, { "FirstName": "John",
>   "LastName": "Smith" }]

I am posting my answer as it may help to anybody that face such type of issue in future.